# fixed size for words for storing in a file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, class, stream

I have this program which writes the firstname and lastname of a person to a file.
When i open the file to see its contents, the words are right beside each other, without any space between them.For example,if the input is Bill and Gates,then these words are stored in file as follows:

```
BillGates
```

But instead i want to store them as two seperate words each having fixed field length.Like this.

```
Bill      Gates     
--------------------
```

Each word takes up 10 units of space.how to do it?Here's the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
    char fname[11];
    char lname[11];
};

ostream & operator << (ostream & obj,Person & p)
{
    obj << p.fname << p.lname;
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream ofile("person.txt");
    Person P;
    cout << "Enter details \n";
    cin >> P.fname >> P.lname;
    ofile << P;
    ofile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you try `std::setw`? What do you do with longer names?

Comment: @Walter I can write them to file using `setw` But while reading them back from the file, i still get combined words rather than seperate words.How to read them in the same way that they are stored.?

Comment: You must, of course, explicitly write the space between them as in `out << setw(10) << p.fname << ' ' << setw(10) << p.lname;`. Reading them, the white space is usually eaten by the `istream`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the output values. And to keep the left formatting you can set the format flag for the output stream. Example follows:

```
int main()
{
   ofstream ofile("person.txt");
   Person P;
   cout << "Enter details \n";
   cin >> P.fname >> P.lname;
   ofile.setf(ofile.left);
   ofile.width(10);
   ofile << P.fname;
   ofile << P.lname;
   ofile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

This gives you your 10 character wide fields, while also keeping the left justification.